# implode result still not as expected

Tags: php

I process some text files that represented in the code below :

the code :

```
$file = file($files);
$lines = str_replace("'", '', $file);
$noMultipleSpace = removeMultipleSpaces($lines);
$fileContents = array();
foreach($noMultipleSpace as $line) {
    if (isLatin($line) && count(preg_split('/\s+/', $line)) > 25) {
        $newContent = preg_split('/\\.\\s*/', $line);
        foreach($newContent as $newsContent) {
            $pos1 = stripos($newsContent, ':');
            if ($pos1 == false && count(preg_split('/\s+/', $newsContent) > 3) && isLatin($newsContent)) {
                $fileContents[] = $newsContent;
            }
        }
        $content = implode('.', $fileContents);
    }
}​
```

with the function :

```
function isLatin($string) {
 return preg_match('/^\\s*[a-z,A-Z]/', $string) > 0;
}

function removeMultipleSpaces($string){
 return preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',$string);
}
```

but, in the implode process, the dot paste in the next sentence. for example `sentence1 .Sentence2`. My expectation is `sentence1. Sentence2`. what's wrong? thank you :)

the input is text files, for example :

```
ChengXiang Zhai
Department of Computer Science University of Illinois at Urbana Champaign

ABSTRACT
Temporal Text Mining (TTM) is concerned with discovering temporal patterns in text 
information collected over time. Since most text information bears some time stamps, TTM has many applications in multiple domains, such as summarizing events in news articles and
revealing research trends in scientific literature. In this paper, we study a particular TTM 
task ­ discovering and summarizing the evolutionary patterns of themes in a text stream. We
define this new text mining problem and present general probabilistic methods for solving
this problem through (1) discovering latent themes from text; (2) constructing an evolution
graph of themes; and (3) analyzing life cycles of themes. Evaluation of the proposed methods
on two different domains (i.e., news articles and literature) shows that the proposed 
methods can discover interesting evolutionary theme patterns effectively. Categories and 
Subject Descriptors: H.3.3 [Information Search and Retrieval]: Clustering General Terms: 
Algorithms Keywords: Temporal text mining, evolutionary theme patterns, theme threads, 
clustering

1.

INTRODUCTION
```

I wanna get the important sentence only, from `Temporal Text Mining (TTM)...` until `effectively`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve, also please provide example input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intermediate sentences appear to have a trailing space, causing the imploded delimiter to appear off.

Try this:

```
$file = file($files);
$lines = str_replace("'", '', $file);
$noMultipleSpace = removeMultipleSpaces($lines);
$fileContents = array();
foreach($noMultipleSpace as $line) {
    if (isLatin($line) && count(preg_split('/\s+/', $line)) > 25) {
        $newContent = preg_split('/\\.\\s*/', $line);
        foreach($newContent as $newsContent) {
            $pos1 = stripos($newsContent, ':');
            if ($pos1 == false && count(preg_split('/\s+/', $newsContent) > 3) && isLatin($newsContent)) {
                $fileContents[] = $newsContent;
            }
        }
        $fileContents = array_map('trim', $fileContents);
        $content = implode('.', $fileContents);
    }
}​
```